"The earth was formless and void" Did the earth exist before God created the world?
Gen 1:2 reads:

"The earth WAS without form and void"; Form-structure void-nothing occupied the earth.
"Darkness WAS upon the deep"; Total darkness upon the waters.
"The Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters." Water was on the earth

The earth was all of water. Water planet after the dino age/ice age/melting/water planet when God found the earth.

Welcome, Lisa, to BHSX.  Thanks for your excellent question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Scripture is exceedingly careful about this kind of concept. 'Before the foundation of the world' refers to kosmos ('the habitable world') not ge (the earth). These are two different concepts, it should be noted.

I have answered this previously under a question which may be considered related or even a duplicate 'Waste and Void'. Tohu and bohu, therefore, is, to me, a matter of the absence of glory that, by a distinct absence, draws attention to itself. The earth was inglorious - and distinctly so..

Simple but nevertheless great question. You have another upvote. Way to start, and if you favorably regard my comment to @Dottard, then you must also "appreciate" his answer??

I don't understand the question. Gen 1:1 literally says God created the Earth, implying unambiguously (to me) that it did not exist before. What is unclear about that?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - the situation with "earth" is not as simple at you appear to suggest - the Hebrew word simply means land - the idea of "planet earth" is very modern.  In any case, the opening statement of Gen 1:1 is a summary of what follows.  The earth, or more precisely, "land" was created on day #3 as noted in my answer.

@Dottard Of course not a planet, but land, a region (all meanings of הָאָֽרֶץ), that is formless and void. After that, God creates order and structure and detail. I am reading this as an entirely linear account of events. Is that not a mainstream reading?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - Yes, the account is simple and linear.  Gen 1:1, 2 is and introduction and Gen 2:1-3 is the conclusion.

@Dottard What exactly do you mean with "introduction"? If you mean that it is a summary of events (i.e., "He created everything") which are detailed (land and sea, light, animals etc.) in the remaining part of chapter 1, I beg to disagree — I think verse 1 sentence 1 means exactly what it says: "Earth" (in the sense of some place to reside in/on) was created. This is simply the stage. Sentence 2 says that it was empty and formless, which He is about to fix in the remaining verses. Likewise, 2:1-3 is a linear continuation of the story: It is complete, He rests, He blesses.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - yes - V1 & 2 form an introduction.  V2 in particular is what existed before day 1.  The "earth" was created by separating land from sea is per day 3.

This question is similar to: Does a wasted, formless and void earth in Gen. 1:2 imply a previously existing world?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I greet you in turn, and I would also like to say a few things, since I have done a lot of work on this particular part of genesis.
After studies of what the land was like and where it was when it was created by God, I have come to the conclusion that most translations - except for the Septuagint - regardless of language dialect, are wrong in their translation of verse 1:2. I will quote, in order, the original text together with a transcription in English characters, the Septuagint with its translation, and an analysis of the Hebrew and its translation, which I believe to be the correct one, and finally analyze the cause of this rendering.
Translation 1:1-2
(Hebrew text)
בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית בָּרָ֣א אֱלֹהִ֑ים אֵ֥ת הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם וְאֵ֥ת הָאָֽרֶץ׃ 2 וְהָאָ֗רֶץ הָיְתָ֥ה תֹ֨הוּ֙ וָבֹ֔הוּ וְחֹ֖שֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י תְה֑וֹם וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם׃
(Transcription of Hebrew text in English characters [hyphens indicate articles, conjunctions and prepositions, while lower hyphens indicate a conjunctive state, commonly: hyphenated Hebrew text)
1 be-reshíth bará elohím et ha-shamáyim we-et ha-árets. 2 we-ha-árets hayethá tóhu wa-vóhu we-chóshech al_pené tehóm, we-rúach elohím merachéfeth al_pené ha-máyim.
(Translation of the Septuagint)
Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἐποίησεν ὁ θεὸς τὸν οὐρανὸν καὶ τὴν γῆν. 2 ἡ δὲ γῆ ἦν ἀόρατος καὶ ἀκατασκεύαστος, καὶ σκότος ἐπάνω τῆς ἀβύσσου, καὶ πνεῦμα θεοῦ ἐπεφέρετο ἐπάνω τοῦ ὕδατος.
(Transcription of the translation of the Septuagint)
1 en arche epíesen o theós ton uranón ke ten ghen. 2 e dhe ghe en aóratos ke akataskévastos, ke skótos epáno tes avíssu, ke pnévma theú epefereto epáno tu ídhatos.
(Translation of the translation of the Septuagint)
1 In the beginning God created (or made) the heavens and the earth. 2 And the earth was invisible and inarticulate, and darkness was above the whole sea, and a wind of God blew with violence above the water.
(Analysis and grammar of the words of the Hebrew text)
בְּרֵאשִׁ֫ית (preposition ב [in, into, inside], noun ראשית [the head as a primary point, head, principle as a base or starting point; generally: initial point])
בָרָ֫א (verb Qal, 3 masculine person, as a complete action [with suffix]: created [he])
אֱלֹהִ֫ים (plural of the noun: god; referring to the one and almighty God)
אֵת (particle which often denotes the accusative case in Greek grammar, which denotes the indicative sense; also, it is compounded with a conjunctive state [with, together])
הַשָּׁמַ֫יִם (article joined with the plural noun: heaven; but as a single form [can also be translated as singular])
וְאֵ֫ת (conjunction: and- [see above])
הָאָ֫רֶץ (article joined to the noun: earth, dry land)
וְהָאָ֫רֶץ (conjunction: and- joined to the noun [see above])
הָיְתָה (verb Qal, with the meaning of a complete event [with suffix], 3rd person feminine: was [she], became [she])
תֹ֫הוּ (masculine noun; literal translation: unsupported sign; synecdocheically: indistinguishable sign, unknown sign, invisible sign; unformed sign, non-existent/unrepresentable sign)
וָבֹ֫הוּ (conjunction joined to a noun; literal translation: house that is not supported; synecdocheically: unbuilt, áktistos (Greek word used to denote the raising of a building through construction), without of house's structure [not accessible to host life]; uninhabitable, desolate, empty, void, without a trace of life)
וְחֹ֫שֶךְ (conjunction “and” joined with noun: darkness)
עַל-פְּנֵי (preposition: upon, on, against; joined to a local noun: face, surface, area, etc.)
תְהוֹם (noun: abyss, ocean, the sea as the boundless and unexplored as well as unknown)
וְר֫וּחַַ (noun: breath, wind, air, spirit)
אֱלֹהִים (see above)
מְרַחֶ֫פֶת (participle Piel [intense energy], feminine gender: moving with momentum, with speed, with force, etc.)
עַל-פְּנֵי (see above)
הַמָּ֫יִם (article joined with plural noun: water/waters)
(Translation of the Hebrew text according to the Common Interpretation of English translations)
1 In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth. 2 And the earth was without form and void, and darkness was upon the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.
I will take the liberty of partially disagreeing with this translation, and change it slightly to correspond, in my opinion, with the Hebrew text (in parentheses where there are dots, it is done deliberately for analysis below of the translation according to the context of the text, to explain why such a translation would be used).
(Transcription-Translation of the Hebrew text)
1 (be-reshíth) In the beginning (bará elohím) God created (et ha-shamáyim we-et ha-árets) the heavens and the earth. 2 We-ha-árets hayethá (And the earth was) tóhu wa-vóhu (...) we-chóshech al_pené tehóm (and darkness upon the face of the abyss) we-rúach (...) elohím (God's) merachéfeth (...) al_pené ha-máyim (upon the area of water).
According to what we know today about the ancient alphabet used by the ancient Hebrew people, perhaps contemporary to Moses, so according to this logic, I may be able to give an interpretation of these Hebrew letters.
תֹהוּ (tohu)
sign, presence of man, or opening (i.e. a gap in this case) and pillar.
We take the noun "tóhu," and say that, in order to select the correct translation of the word in this verse, it must, it is understood, fit the context of Genesis chapter 1. Hence, therefore, immediately the unformed is rejected; for, it is not consistent with the meaning of the word in its context. I mean, in short, that many translations get it wrong. Thus, since the earth had been created, and had taken its original shape, with mountains, hills, plains, rifts, etc., it is not conceivable that the word “unformed” should be inferred in the second verse. Hence we have the translations: sign that is not supported; synecdocheically: indistinguishable sign, unknown sign, invisible sign. We have two clues which help us to find the correct word, and these are verse 1, where it testifies that the earth was created, and verses 9-10, where it testifies that the earth was under the water. Therefore, we have the translations: indistinguishable sign, unknown sign, and invisible sign. Of these three, indistinguishable denotes something far away and inaccessible that may be discernible as a speck on the horizon, but does not quite fit the context. We have unknown sign, which is something general as a term, i.e. it does not specify in the second verse what its position represents, and we have invisible, which happens to fit and tie in perfectly with the context, and, coincidentally, has been chosen by the Septuagint as a translation of this noun "tóhu".
I have to comment that I'm Greek and a Bible translator, not that it implies anything important, but I want to say that being Greek is not the reason I prefer and honor the Septuagint translation because it's in my native language (probably the language of my ancestors), but because it was done, according to the information we have, in Alexandria, where Greek was then the common language in the region, and the Jews had developed their learning of it and used it as a second or almost first language of conversation and understanding, plus they were Jews who had been trained in the Law of Moses and in the concepts of texts and traditions. It would therefore be unheard of not to take them seriously, not to mention more than that... For if anyone today, in the 21st century, happens to have historical knowledge of that time, let alone those Jews probably knew the history and traditions of the Law and the Prophets a few years before them. The closer one is to the autograph manuscript, the more of an eyewitness one is. This is not to say that the Septuagint is infallible, but we must give credence to their words because they have a rich history and rich value, translated by the Jews themselves.
בֹ֫הוּ (vóhu)
house, gap (as above) and pillar.
We come now to the noun "vóhu". Again I will use the same contextual pattern. So we have the translations: house that does not stand; synecdocheically: unbuilt (the Greek language has also the word: áktistos, that means also unbuilt, which has the meaning of elevation, related to the construction of a building), without of house's structure (with the meaning of familiar structure for inhabitants); uninhabited, desolate, empty, void, without a trace of life. Here I will use logic. Since the earth is under water, it goes without saying that it will be uninhabitable (and I don't think that's what Moses had in mind, i.e. to say that the earth is empty of every trace of life, from fish and birds to animals and people). As we would say, the Titanic sank hundreds of years ago and is in the ocean and is empty of people. So, the word "empty" does not apply to a land that is self-evidently empty. It sounds somewhat without logic or reason, otherwise it would be something I would say in a humorous way. For regardless of what meaning the first word "tohu" represents, we can know with certainty that the earth was under the water, from other evidence in chapter 1 (see vv. 9-10), and that the earth was created (see v. 1). Therefore, we have the words: unbuild, without of house's structure (as a familiar structure for inhabitants). The verb in Greek “áktistos” does not fit perfectly because it refers to building material for buildings, because God made arrangements, and after making those arrangements, He then created the families of living things - trees/plants/crows, fish and birds, land animals and humans. So we go to the unbuild, which refers to the earth as uncreated also, as a general building set, so it doesn't fit; so we are left with "without a house's structure (with the meaning of familiar structure which represents a house of mens)". Now, this means an assembled whole which, in itself, is a house's structure; e.g. luminous bodies contribute to the realm of planet earth being a house's structure, i.e. accessible to accommodate life. The firmament that holds the clouds together so that it rains and makes clouds also contribute. The earth, as separated from the sea, contributes to being a house's structure; and we would also say that the vegetation of trees and grasses is the result of a house's structure. In general, the deep meaning in house's structure is what can to accommodate life. Of course, it also has metaphorical meanings. Now, it fits with the Septuagint's "kataskévasma" (kataskevasménos > akataskévastos), which has two meanings that fit the Hebrew noun "vóhu", one being that which is modified or completed (comes into final form), or that which lacks proper equipment, or unfinished. Now, the “kataskévasma”, essentially the meaning, I think, is that which is an assembled “organized whole” and can “accommodate” a person, as for example, we have the 2nd word skévasma > skévos, which would essentially mean an assembled set of materials that all together form a container. A computer, is made up of the materials with which it was created, and within it are embedded electronic components that, all harmonized together, and together with the screen, show the person sitting at it, the ability to process folders, files, surf the internet, etc. It is therefore not only a “structured body”, i.e. a body that has a composition, but also a set of scientific instruments that guide and serve the person electronically. We could therefore call it "house's structure" (although we don't usually say it and it is not a handy word to define a computer today in our language, but it is handy for humans in the sense that it is hospitable and favourable to them). And this is one meaning of the Hebrew letter "ב", which also symbolizes the earth in the sense that it is hospitable to man, i.e. his place of residence. Man dwells on the earth. This is his dwelling place. A synecdoche of meaning, then, in this sense, and a very simple one at that, would be inhospitable (as indeed we would say today that the earth in the beginning was a chaos). But because we want to define the translation, we ask the following question: what defines something as inhospitable to man or as chaotic? Something that not consists a house's structure!
ר֫וּחַ (rúach) and מְרַחֶ֫פֶת (merachéfeth) from the native root of רחף
In order to determine the meaning of ר֫וּחַ we must first find out what Moses is trying to tell us with the word מְרַחֶ֫פֶת. We also have the information that this action was from God, or of God Himself (Holy Spirit). We say then, the native root רחף marks some iconography. These are a) a head, b) a great wall or small wall, and c) a mouth. If we try to pronounce the word correctly, the pronunciation itself gives us an essential meaning. By pronouncing "ר", we mark a "flow". By pronouncing "ח" we mark an exhalation (specifically, here, this letter represents "h", as we pronounce Greek words such as: historia, harmony, etc), and by pronouncing "ף" we mark a lip-blowing. A flow that exhales with a lip-blowing. Here it specifically identifies, I think, the energy of the wind. Which is in a state of outflow, where it exhales causing a blowing. Anyway, it is an inference of the meaning of this word, which, perhaps, will help us to arrive at the true meaning of the words. Now, this word is in the form of a participle but it is also in the form of Piel (intense active). So, according to what I personally deduced, it is a wind, which blew with force on the face of the sea. And I say wind, and not the Spirit of God, because the Spirit is immaterial; therefore, according to simple logic, but without putting God in a mould (if, as a matter of fact, it was the Holy Spirit, as a number of ancient Christians say [Note: I am a christian; and I say this because this, the view of the wind, is that of the Jews.]), the Holy Spirit, as immaterial, has nothing to do with the sea which is of matter. Whereas the wind, proceeding from God, as a matter, waves the waters of the sea, and creates a disturbance in it, according to the meaning of the following Hebrew word. Now, why the wind should blow the waters of the sea, I know not. On the other hand, the Holy Spirit sanctified the waters of the sea, according to Tertullian, as he quotes the baptism of man in the water, where the Holy Spirit intercedes and comes and sanctifies the waters. But would the Holy Spirit have loudly blown the waters of the sea at the beginning of creation? Therefore, according to this reasoning, perhaps the Hebrew word ר֫וּחַַ, identifies a wind, according to the context of the verse. "And a wind proceeding from God blew with violence over the expanse of the waters."
But here another, equally difficult problem arises in translation. When Moses wrote: "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth" - what did he mean by "heaven"? Because in verse 6 he speaks of a firmament which God called "heaven". And in verse 14 he said to become luminaries in the firmament of heaven. For if he calls heaven the atmosphere of the earth, then if there would be no, and he meant heaven in verse 1, the universe, then there would be no wind blowing in the sea, and that with power. It is possible that Moses and his contemporaries did not form in their minds the existence of the universe. But, rather, they had formed the sky, i.e. what they saw with their eyes, as being the beyond, regardless of whether it meant the lifeless and natural laws of the planet earth in the beyond; this, they probably did not know. Therefore, firmament, probably, meant by Moses the visible sky, on which the sun and moon were fixed, according to Moses' account. The point, however, is that if the sky already existed, then there would have been no mention by Moses of the establishment of a firmament for the separation of water, in liquid form and in the form of psychotic water vapour; for if we suppose that the atmosphere of the earth existed, then, automatically, it would also function as a firmament of waters in clouds; otherwise, there was neither wind in verse 2, nor sky in verse 1. Therefore, the non-existence of heaven does not justify the wind in verse 2. Therefore, I conclude that (though it seems discouraging to say this), Moses did not have the scientific knowledge, consistent with the laws of nature of planet earth, but somehow they entered his mind, or, he knew stories, that told a creation related to the truth and concise; perhaps from Egypt? I do not know.
Summary and translation
So we have the earth, which was created, and which, according to verses 9-10, was under the water. Therefore, the concept of invisible (unseen, under the water) is appropriate here, and not unformed, which means: without form/shape. We take also the sense of the second noun of verse 2, בֹ֫הוּ, and say that the earth was inhospitable, i.e. a chaos, which chaos is determined by the fact that it had no house's structure; i.e., God's arrangements had not come which formed a whole complex for the purpose of making the earth hospitable to man and to all animal beings in general. Also, we have a wind coming from God, which blew with violence upon the surface of the sea.
1 In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth. 2 And the earth was invisible and without of house's structure, and darkness was upon the face of the whole sea, and a wind from God blew with violence upon the surface of the waters.
This is purely my explanation, and I am not relying on multiple sources, but it is a conclusion of my own. Of course, I may be wrong.

+1 Terrific answer! Thank you for the insights, which I've saved! Please note that researchers now have evidence that the earth may have started as a "water world" after all: https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2021/04/harvard-scientists-determine-early-earth-may-have-been-a-water-world/. While Moses compiled Torah, the evidence keeps mounting that most of Genesis was originally recorded on clay tablets long before Moses despite academic scoffing. The evidence includes colophone phrases at the end of sections, catch phrases and derived tablet dimensions in the ancient Babylonian style.

I must admit that at first glance all I saw was this elongated wall of words, although  with at least some paragraph separation, and was therefore a little off-putt by same. I slowly, however, changed from being disenchanted to highly enlightened. Initially, I just picked out a phrase/paragraph or two, in order to get a feeling as to whether this may be a worthy literary endeavor, or not. Then after deciding that it may indeed have worth, I committed to not only read the whole narrative but also to inwardly digest. This is a knowledgeable and very credible work to be sure. Many thanks, + 1.

Thanks for you proposals. I noticed a correlation between the violent blowing and the strong wind at Pentecost.

Welcome to the site, George, and for this fulsome answer. You certainly have done a lot of work on this! Your last paragraph alone makes me glad to upvote you.

Thanks a lot for these wonderful comments! I am rly glad of your speech! But the only one who is a teacher, is the Lord. I may have formed a nice text development, but there is no one like the teacher! Anyway, it is not entirely certain that this is how things are.

The LXX here adds significant credibility, since the Greek translation is a snapshot of how Hebrew scholars under the auspices of the Sanhedrin interpreted the Hebrew around 250 years before Christ (however, Origen's later edits to the LXX introduced some issues).
However, the "phrase structure" (aka syntax) of Genesis 1:1 allows two options pointed out by Dr. Michael Heiser, who had a PhD in ancient Hebrew.

"In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth . . . " This makes verse 1 an independent clause, verse 2 a dependent clause, followed by verse 3, an independent clause.

"When God began to create the heavens and the earth . . . "
This makes both verse 1 and 2 dependent clauses, and verse 3 the independent clause.


The difference between 1 and 2 depends on the vowel pointing of the first letter of the first word. However, vowel points were added by the Masoretes around the 8th or 10th centuries AD.
Option 1 would require a kamatz (T) under the first letter while a shva (:) would "point to" option 2.
So, which pointing has been passed down to us through the centuries?
See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmFE-qjoksc (10 minutes). Or you can check for yourself here: https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/1.htm

In general it is a matter of debate and needs extensive knowledge of Hebrew, such as knowledge of distant tradition. Various opinions are expressed. Personally, I can't say that Dr. Michael S. Heiser is wrong, but I can't say that he is right either. The major critical edition of the BHQ (Biblia Hebraica Quinta), in the commentary it provides, with reference to the tradition of words, states, concerning the first letter of the first word ב, that some manuscripts enlarge it; as do also the majority of Hebrew editions.

BHQ also says, that Norzi, in Minhat Shay, explicitly mentions the enlarged ב as the correct way of writing it. However, I have researched some manuscripts that I have been able to access, such as Codex Hillely and the manuscript in the Bodleian library, and they have it enlarged. In the Leningrad Codex, as I saw, also in this, it is as if someone had repainted it and enlarged it;

However, the reference to capital letters, in this manuscript, made on p. 466 of the book, or on p. 936 of the website, entitled אליו אותיות גדולות (= here are the capital letters), the initial ב of the first word of Genesis is also included; https://archive.org/details/Leningrad_Codex/page/n935/mode/2up this means that it indicates the translation: In the beginning God created etc.

The editions of Kennicott, Ginsburg, Baer, Van der Hooght, Bamberger-Hildesheimer-Lehmann, and the three editions of Kittel (revisions, of 2 volumes each), have it enlarged. On the other hand, the last 2 critical editions of the Hebrew Bible, BHS and the major BHQ, have it in normal form. Of the Rabbinic Bible rabbis, Rashi, Rashbam, Ibn Ezra, and a further, unnamed, commentary, state that, grammatically it is translated as: when God began to create etc.; while Kimhi agrees with the OJPS (Old Jewish Publication Society) translation which translates as: In the beginning God created etc.

@George F, I've noticed that in English, the reading could also be "In beginning" without the article, "the." But, I'm not going to argue with someone who earned a PhD in Hebrew (I once corresponded with Dr. Heiser on a different issue in Hebrew). This would be like a fight between Bambi and Godzilla. Yes, I'd be the Bambi.

Bring me Godzila! :P

Grammatically he is correct, and I embrace him. He said with the qamats down to ב, the translation is: In the beginning God created etc. which with the long vowel "a" adds emphasis and is translated accordingly. And when it has shewa, it is translated with a conjugated state.

We observe the following about the tight literary structure that is Gen 1:1 - 2:3 -

Each day follows the strict formula, “And God said, ‘Let…’ …And there was evening and morning – the nth day.”  Thus, the first day of creation week begins in Gen 1:3, and the sixth day ends with Gen 1:31.  That is, Gen 1:2 is not part of the first day of creation activity.
In all but day 2 we also have the phrase, “And God saw that it was good (Gen 1:4, 10, 12, 18, 21, 25, 31) scattered through the text as well.
The two halves of creation week follow the same pattern.  The first half (days 1-3) mostly concerns the act of separating (eg, waters above from waters below, light from darkness, land from sea, etc.), while the second half (days 4-6) mostly concerns populating these separated habitats with living creatures or lights (the sun and moon are not explicitly mentioned).  This directly follows the pattern set up in Gen 1:2 where the earth is declared, “tohu and bohu” = formless and empty; God then proceeds to form and fill.
There are three phases of creation involving light, water, and dry ground.  Each required two steps separated by three days.  In the case of the land (the third phase of day 3 and day 6), two distinct creation acts are recorded each time, each terminated by the declaration that the result was good: on day 3 it is the separation of dry land from the water and then the creation of vegetation; on day 6 God made the land produce animals, and then the land (or soil Gen 2:7) was made to produce mankind.
The creation of the sun and moon is not recorded in this passage.  All that is stated is that God created lights in the expanse of the heaven (“sky” NIV, not outer space or the starry heaven), which according to Gen 1:6 is what separated the waters below (what became on day 3 rivers, lakes and seas) from the waters above (presumably the source of dew, rain and snow in the atmosphere).  Hebrew has perfectly good words for “sun” (שֶׁמֶשׁ shemesh) and “moon” (יָרֵחַ yareach) that the author obviously goes to some trouble to avoid using.
The passage contains several nomenclature or definition statements which are introduced by the phrase, “God called the…”.  This occurs for “day” and “night” (1:4), the “sky” or “heaven” (1:8), and the “land” or “earth” and the “seas” (1:10).  All these definition statements occur in the first three days only.  The naming of the living creatures was (presumably) to be left to Adam (2:19).
Further, there is no record (in Gen 1:1–2:3) of God creating planet Earth on any of the six days.  Nor is there any record of creating the water covering the planet – this was apparently all done before the first day of creation week which began in V3.  Thus, at the beginning of the first day of creation week, the Earth consisted of a “formless”, planet covered in water, totally lifeless and dark, over which the Spirit of God was moving (Gen 1:2).
Gen 1 is written from a phenomenological point of view - what an observer would simply see. It is NOT a scientific nor astronomical record. This is reinforced with passages like Eccl 1:5 about the sun and moon rising and setting and hurrying back again.
The fact that the sun produces its own light and the moon is a reflector of light (as we now know from astronomical analysis) is quite irrelevant to the record of Gen 1 because all that matters is that they are both sources of light for the inhabitants on earth. The stars are also sources of light as also recorded elsewhere, such as Eze 32:7, Jer 31:35, etc.
One of the several functions of the Gen 1 record is as type of salvation. God takes a world that (Gen 1:2) “tohu and bohu and hosek” = formless and void and dark; and by the end of the record we have, (v31) “And God looked upon all that He had made, and indeed, it was very good.” That is, we have the opposite - form, value and brightness!
It is not necessary for the author of a Bible passage to fully understand what is being revealed. We see this spectacularly in passages like Dan 8:27 and others. Thus, it is possible that the author was inspired to write the passage in the style and vocabulary they did to avoid misconceptions and unfounded claims.
The “vault” or “firmament” (רָקִיעַ raqia) is called heavens (שָׁמַיִם shamayim) Gen 1:8 and represents the space between the waters below and waters above.
The Bible writers of Gen 1 makes no attempt to distinguish between what we now call the atmosphere and outer space beyond the atmosphere - they had no language nor understanding of these things and it did not matter to them. Heaven was anything above the earth or soil (where crops were grown). Birds flew in the heaven (Gen 1:20, 26, 28, 30, 2:19, 20, 6:7, etc); water came from above the heavens (Gen 1:6, 7, 7:11, 8:2, etc); the sun, moon and stars existed in the heavens (Gen 1:14), etc.
Similarly, there is no concept of “planet earth” in Gen 1 - it is entirely foreign to the entire Bible. “earth” (אֶרֶץ erets) is simply dry, arable land (Gen 1:10) that makes agriculture possible.
It is very significant that in the creation record of Gen 1 -


The heavens are created on day #2 (Gen 1:8)
The earth is created in day #3 (Gen 1:10)

Therefore, a simple reading of Gen 1:1–2:3 suggests that a formless, worthless, dark, lifeless, watery planet already existed at (ie, before) the beginning of creation week.  This suggests that God had previously created it – a suggestion supported by Job 38:4-7, “Where were you when I laid the foundations of the earth? … Who laid its cornerstone while the morning stars and all the sons of God shouted for joy?”  Thus, other life forms existed elsewhere in the universe (apart from God) who witnessed the creation of the Earth during the planet’s very foundation.
However, there was nothing on earth such as any life, etc, before that first creation week apart from water.

The "Flood", of biblical proportions in Noah's time, covered the whole Earth with water but never did I think that that was not the "first" earthly complete water covering. You and the OP have now just brought home to me that that most extraordinary event was indeed "secondary" to the time before the all too familiar "7 Day" creative account. Your exhaustive but easily understandable expose, of all of Gen, 1:1 - 2:3  is much appreciated. Very well delineated for sure. It's a definite upvote from me. Can't believe I'm the first to give you credit here. Hopefully, others will follow.

@OldeEnglish - many thanks, good friend.

The English translation using "was" is neither here nor there: that's just an auxiliary verb we use to make past tenses.
But a similar question arises in the original language.
Joseph Blenkinsopp writes at length about it in 'Creation, Un-Creation, Re-Creation, 2010'
p.30:-

By construing the opening sentence as a main clause rather than a
subordinate temporal clause, this version provided warrant for a
theology of creation from nothing (creatio ex nihilo) , the standard
and orthodox theological understanding of creation in early Judaism
and Christianity. Creation out of nothing can be argued on
philosophical and theological grounds, it was accepted in Judaism
before Christianity (see e.g. 2 Macc. 7:28 where it is explicitly
stated), and if not explicitly formulated in the New Testament is
hinted at indirectly (Rom. 4:17; 1Cor. 1:28; Heb 11:3). All this
notwithstanding, it has been known at least from the Middle Ages - for
example in the commentary of the Jewish scholar Rashi - that from the
linguistical and exegetical point of view this reading of Gen 1:1-2 is
not the preferred option in strictly exegetical terms.

He advances a second argument: that in the history-of-ideas (i) Gods don't necessarily create ex nihilo - e.g. in the Enuma Elish they only appear on line 8 and (ii) they sometimes have to contend with chaotic forces.
There is a third argument: that some pre-Christian Jewish texts have different sequences of creation - e.g. Wisdom being created first in Prov. 8:22-31.

The LORD possessed me at the beginning of his work, the first of his
acts of old.

His best argument though, I think is in a different book (maybe 'Genesis: A Commentary'?): that the second word of the bible בָּרָ֣א=bara can't mean to create ex nihilo - since it's also used for the creation of humanity (Gen 1:27-28). In the sense of make/shape/create it's only used of God. Of humans it's used for (e.g.) clearing a forest (Joshua 17:15) and making someone fat with offerings (1 Samuel 2:29).
How Blenkinsopp would answer the OP I think is on p.32 - the pre-existing material was the 'shapeless mass'='tohu wabohu' occupying the space between the upper waters and the lower waters.

"The English translation using "was" is neither here nor there" — It's more significant than that. Hebrew normally doesn't use "to be" to indicate that something "is". For instance, "darkness was upon" in Hebrew is simply "darkness upon", the "was" was supplied by the translators  (in KJV it is italicized to indicate this). But "the earth was without form is a real Hebrew verb, one that means "to transform or to have become". A better translation would be "the earth became an empty wasteland". See my Creation Verbs in Genesis.

Genesis 1:1

1 In the beginning, God created the heavens and the earth.

This verse is summarizing what is going to happen. In the beginning - a non-time specific statement - God created the sky above and the land.

2 The earth was without form and void, and darkness was over the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God was hovering over the face of the waters.

Next we get several statements that describe the pre-creation state of the earth in different ways.
"Without form and void" is a way of talking about the unordered, uninhabited nothingness. "Darkness was over the face of the deep" or "darkness was on the face of the deep abyss" A dark chaotic ocean, a way of describing the non-reality that preceded creation.

And the Spirit of God was hovering over the face of the waters

And, in the midst of the darkness, the chaos, the unordered, uninhabited nothingness is God's presence ready to bring order so that life can flourish.
Genesis 1:1-2 tells us that God created the earth, the land and sky out of an unordered, chaotic, non-reality.
The earth did not exist before God created the world.

Yes because of the opening statement in the Book of Genesis, that the earth was created alongside the heavens in the beginning. Now between these two instances of time where God created the heavens and the earth and when he said let there be light, time passed. Whether the time that passed is very small or billions of years we do not know but anything that can be seen in the universe was created, that is according to the book of Genesis and The Book of John.
Genesis 1:1

In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.

John 1:3

All things were made through Him, and without Him nothing was made that was made

The two verses show that God created the earth, how much time passed between creation of heaven and earth and God saying let there be light cannot be established but be sure God created everything visible and invisible

Hebrews 2:10 ESV: For it was fitting that he, for whom and by whom all things exist, in bringing many sons to glory, should make the founder of their salvation perfect through suffering.
This, as well as Genesis 1:1, makes it clear that God created the world: Earth, and everything we can see or otherwise sense.
[Act 17:24 NIV] "The God who made the world and everything in it is the Lord of heaven and earth and does not live in temples built by human hands."
As Lord of everything, He necessarily created all the natural laws of physics, biology, etc. In Genesis 1 we see that he did this in an order and time frame that could not be the mere natural result of starting with these laws and matter.
"The world" is the earth plus everyone on it, hence the Earth necessarily was created before it was populated.  This happened in the early darkness of Day 1, according to verses 1-5.
