Was earth created on the water(s)?
In Genesis 1:2 we see that the waters are already present on or before day one.

2 Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters. [Gen 1:2 NIV]

Is it not clear in the biblical order of creation that the earth was created out of the water(s) and from the water(s) it appeared?

9 And God said, "Let the water under the sky be gathered to one place, and let dry ground appear." And it was so. 10 God called the dry ground "land," and the gathered waters he called "seas." And God saw that it was good. [Gen 1:9-10 NIV]

Prior to this in verse 8 the waters were up to the vault/firmament.

7 So God made the vault and separated the water under the vault from the water above it. And it was so. [Gen 1:7 NIV]



Berean Strong's Lexicon 3245. yasad : To establish, to found, to lay a foundation



[Psa 24:1-2 NIV] Of David. A psalm. The earth is the LORD's, and everything in it, the world, and all who live in it; 2 for he founded it on the seas and established it on the waters.


[Psa 136:6 NIV] who spread out the earth upon the waters, His love endures forever.


Where does it say that ANYTHING existed prior to day 1? And besides there is no punctuation in the Hebrew, and it is widely accepted that the first three verses are all part of the first day and only the first day. We also have the witness of the NT that tells us that ALL things were made during. Reaction both invisible and visible, hence there is nothing that could have existed that is created prior to Creation which started on day 1.

@NihilSineDeo - You seem to be operating under a false "Creatio Ex Nihilo" assumption in which something that is formless and void is still "created" - This is not actually true in Hebrew and Levantine thought and is a 6th BCE-3rd AD century idea. Anything that had not been seperated, formed, or named was not yet "created" in earlier thought... Also, you have another (top) answer on a duplicate of this question...

This question is similar to: When did God create the waters in Genesis 1:2?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And also here:
https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/97656/the-earth-was-formless-and-void-did-the-earth-exist-before-god-created-the-wor Also note that recently researchers have come to believe that the earth was originally completely covered with water, plus isotope ratios seem to indicate that a significant portion of the water on earth are actually older than the sun. Very strange!

@James I think the assumption lies with you, namely that verse one is somehow insufficient to demonstrate the ex nihilo and v2 to describe that which came from the ex nihilo. We both agree there was a gap of time between the description in v1 and v2 only you refuse to acknowledge the word 1 (day) as being the totality of time for vv1-3 because clearly the formless and void at one point was also created and for me there are moments to minutes to at most hours between the creation of the universe in v1 and the description of what it looked like in v2. Question your assumptions, stay within text

@NihilSineDeo - I can demonstrate that historic thought was not from a "Creatio Ex Nihilo" with sources and that the author(s) of Genesis shared this perspective, but not really in the comments. I'll find a good Q and do a writeup and link it. I also don't believe in gap theory or that there was an intended gap between V1 and V2... But that is another matter entirely. What I am saying is that "Formless and Void" == uncreated in the perspective of the author. More to come on that...

@James I understand what you are saying and also I’m not describing the gap theory just using the same nomenclature. Yes you will find some sources in history that did not ascribe to Creatio Ex Nihilo, that doesn’t mean they are correct nor authoritative. I could point to Zoroastrianism and Kabbalah for many ideas that use Scripture but are ultimately incompatible with the whole of Scripture. By all means if you have the time please post your demonstration and link it, I will gladly read it. Are you trying to extrapolate Jer4:23? Is this where you are going? This is what the gap theorist use.

The question is not about the waters!

@rps the earth in its raw form was inside the waters G1:1 and God separated the waters with the solid crystalline structure called the firmament G1:6 creating a terrarium with some waters still outside. Then he caused the earth that was still under the waters inside the terrarium to come up above those waters inside the terrarium and be exposed as dry land G1:9. Then he put life forms in the waters and on the earth and in the air under and inside the firmament canopy. 2 Peter 3:5 tells you the earth is from and standing in the waters and this whole thing is NOT hanging on anything Job26:7.


Was earth created on the water(s)?
This question is about the creation of the earth and not about the
waters, so please stick to the subject.

Ok, but the title of your question includes the word, water(s), but I'll do my best.

(In Genesis 1:2 we see that the waters are already present on or
before day one. There is no account of when the waters were created in
the Bible. We want a neat and tucked theology of answers. There is
none, and neither is there any proof text for "Ex Nihilo". God created
from something, and/or he created from himself. This is not nothing.)

It occurs to me that you might be asking about the creation of Planet Earth and the universe.
Where did creation come from?
Ancient cosmologies often describe warring gods, dismemberment, and repurposed body parts in their creation stories. Planet earth is supported on the backs of large animals such as tortoises and elephants. One of the Greek Titans, Atlas, holds up the heavens, and the sun and moon are powerful deities.  In contrast, the Bible contains no similar stories. The sun and moon are simply lamps.
The ancient Septuagint translation of Genesis literally begins like this:

In the beginning, God made the heaven and the earth. But the earth was
unseen and unready; and darkness was upon the abyss. And the Spirit of
God bore upon the water. And God said, “Let there be light!” And there
was light. – Genesis 1:1 (ABP)

So, let’s compare the above description with a Wikipedia description of the early chronology of the universe, the initial “cosmic dark ages” that are believed to have lasted several hundred million years:

Before decoupling occurred, most of the photons in the universe were
interacting with electrons and protons in the photon–baryon fluid. The
universe was opaque or "foggy" as a result. There was light but not
light we can now observe through telescopes. The baryonic matter in
the universe consisted of ionized plasma, and it only became neutral
when it gained free electrons during "recombination", thereby
releasing the photons creating the CMB [Cosmic Microwave Background].
When the photons were released (or decoupled) the universe became
transparent.

Thus, according to current scientific theory, the universe was initially dark and fluid. Then, the universe went through an inflationary stage or two, changed from opaque to transparent, and light became visible.
Please note that 99.9% of people in all of history—and even those alive today worldwide—wouldn’t have any comprehension of the above description. Thus, it’s not unreasonable that the Genesis 1 description is an abstraction, a polemic, and perhaps even functions as an allegory.
And that the universe originated from a singularity and has been expanding—stretching—ever since then, is a relatively new scientific theory. For hundreds of years, it was assumed that the universe was static and infinite, having no beginning or end.
Worldviews, preconceptions, and current theories are all important factors in determining whether something sounds believable.
Regarding the creation of the world and the universe, “ex nihilo,” science currently has no testable explanation. The nature of reality has been and continues to be debated within scientific community. However, it’s becoming increasingly apparent that the basis of our physical reality is a byproduct of information. Let's consider this further.
What is he nature of our physical reality?
Quantum theory is widely accepted by physicists. For example, Vlatko Vedral is a professor of Physics at the University of Oxford who specializes in quantum theory and whose research papers are widely cited expresses the concept this way:

The most fundamental definition of reality is not matter or energy,
but information–and it is the processing of information that lies at
the root of all physical, biological, economic, and social phenomena.

Let’s compare Dr. Vedral’s description to the beginning of the Gospel of John in the New Testament:

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
was God. He was in the beginning with God. All things came into being
through Him, and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come
into being. In Him was life, and the life was the Light of men. The
Light shines in the darkness, and the darkness did not comprehend it.
– John 1:1 (NASB)

“Word” here is translated from the original Greek word, logos, which encompasses meanings in English that include a word, a thought, a concept, a plan, reasoning, and logic—all of which represent information.
This is the most eloquent and powerful description of the creation of our reality—space-time, mass-energy, and gravity (or space-time distortion according to Einstein) in a low-entropy state that I can comprehend.
For your interest, here’s an article about the scientific revolution currently in progress:
https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-quantum-thermodynamics-revolution-20170502/
Conclusion
The Bible doesn't specify when, how, or why the "abyss" or the "waters" formed, and likewise, science is completely clueless about how space-time originated from a singularity of zero volume and infinite mass-energy along with a photon–baryon fluid that somehow "emerged." Genesis names the source as "YHWH" (i.e. God) while science names the source as "multiverse" (i.e. god).
Hope this helps.

No.  The earth / land appeared out of the waters.  Look at the better translation from Young's Literal Translation (YLT).

the earth hath existed waste and void, and darkness [is] on the face of the deep, and the Spirit of God fluttering on the face of the waters,  (Gen. 1:2, YLT)


9 And God saith, Let the waters under the heavens be collected unto one place, and let the dry land be seen:' and it is so. 10 And God calleth to the dry land Earth,' and to the collection of the waters He hath called `Seas;' and God seeth that [it is] good. (Gen. 1:9-10, YLT)

The scriptures say that the "earth" existed in a waste and void form.  This indicates a pre-existing condition of some kind, most probably that YHVH had used it for an earlier work.  But, the dry land was under the waters before YHVH called it forth and separated it from the waters.
But, Psa. 24:1-2 and 136:6 tell us that the earth is set upon the waters. See my blog post Is The Earth Hanging Upon Nothing for a more complete discussion.
In light of Noah's flood when YHVH destroyed the wicked people from off the face of the earth, is it not possible that He had previously flooded the earth from an earlier use?
The NIV is a very faulty translation infected with the biases of the translators. I very rarely ever look at it. See here, here, and here.

+1 mainly because I really dislike anonymous downvotes. Your argument needs to address the issue of whether Genesis 1:1 is the initial act of God or a summary of the six days that follow. This is not a trivial task in my opinion. Also note that recent research indicates that that the interior of the earth contains around three times as much water as all the oceans combined! Apparently, there's a lot we don't understand about planetary formation, despite the extraordinary confidence expressed in the now mostly obsolete textbooks on the subject.

Dieter, thank you.  But, I wonder if your request that I broaden the answer to discuss whether Gen 1:1 is the initial act of God is beyond the OP's question about the earth/land being created on the waters.  I can expand if you  would like, but today's "science" research doesn't agree with the creation account.  Pls read my post cited here.

I believe that the context of the previous verses is crucial for this question. Also, let me note that science is always changing as new discoveries challenge our current understandings. For example, recent data from the Webb telescope has falsified much of what we thought we knew about cosmology.  For another example, take a look at this diagram published by NASA. Notice that light came into existence before the sun and other stars: https://science.nasa.gov/resource/history-of-the-universe/ . Skeptics used to mock Genesis about light forming before the sun. Isn't that interesting?
